# Issues with Checkbox with DHTMLX

Tags: javascript, jsp, dhtmlx

I recently asked a question and got it resolved. It was of great help. But later on i am having trouble fetching the grid. I am creating a checkbox with

```
function eXcell_includeDC(cell){ //the eXcell name is defined here
    if (cell){                // the default pattern, just copy it
        this.cell = cell;
        this.grid = this.cell.parentNode.grid;
    }
    this.edit = function(){} 

    this.isDisabled = function(){ return true; }
    this.setValue=function(val){
    if (val=="Y")
        this.setCValue("<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'/>",val);
    else
        this.setCValue("<input type='checkbox'/>",val);
   }
}
eXcell_includeDC.prototype = new eXcell;
```

The problem am having is when i am fetching the grid, I get the input tag without a closing tag.

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'>
```

This is what i get, that's why the Javascript is throwing an exception.

Comment: `<input>` elements don't require a closing tag. (Unless you are using XHTML, but you don't mention that.) Please [edit] your question to add details of the specific exception that is thrown.

Comment: Can you share the exact text of exception? The above code and the HTML looks valid.